# VirtualBox command works correct in bash, but does not work in nginx

Tags: python, django, bash, nginx, virtualbox

We have a project on nginx/Django, using VirtualBox.
When we try to run command `VBoxManage list runningvms` in nginx, we have the next error:

```
Failed to initialize COM because the global settings directory '/.config/VirtualBox' is not accessible!
```

If we run this command in console, it works fine.

What can we do to make it working good in nginx?

Other details: 
nginx is runned by user "www-data", console - by the other user (Administrator).

Comment: Bash is a shell. Nginx is a webserver. How are you trying to run VirtualBox commands from a webserver?

Comment: process = subprocess.Popen(self.args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, close_fds=True)
stdout_data, stderr_data = process.communicate()

Comment: Related, although unanswered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35624311/booting-virtualbox-vm-as-www-data

Comment: Have a look at the Python API for VirtualBox https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyvbox

Answer (score 0):

We have fixed the issue.

1. There was wrong environment variable "Home" (os.environ['HOME']). We changed it, and so the problem was gone.
2. Using Python API for VB instead of ssh can really help you with that problem, as **RegularlyScheduledProgramming** suggested - we added Python API too.

Thanks!